# Conda list not showing packages in virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am just starting out using virtual environments and I just tried ismply installing pygame into my virtual environment and then using `conda list` to see that it successfully installed but it shows no packages installed.

```
(test) C:\Users\Owner>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (4.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.3 MB 3.3 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6

(test) C:\Users\Owner>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\envs\test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

(test) C:\Users\Owner>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I created a new virtual environment I did not specify what version of python I wanted to use. I thought it would just use the latest version because you can create venv's in multiple languages (python, r) you need to specify python==3.7

Answer (score 0):

on top of the accepted answer, I had to do the following, from the conda virtual environment :

```
pip freeze --user > packages.txt 
pip uninstall -r packages.txt 
pip install -r packages.txt
```